# Changing the user language in an asp.net application based on user choice

Tags: c#

I have web application which supports globalization. So i need to provide user a choice to select a language one he/she logs in. Now the problem is where do i have to make changes to set the user's preferred language.

Comment: I tried to override the InitializeCulture() method but this sets the settings for the current page only.

Comment: One more possible way could be to override the web.config file settings as per the user's selected language. But i think this can affect the settings when another user loggs in.

Comment: I think that this setting should be stored on your user preferrences and be loaded each time the user comes to your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the solution:
I tried the following changes in the global.asax file

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
 if (Session["userCultureInfo"] != null)
  {             
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Session["userCultureInfo"].ToString());
   }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASP.NET profile feature to declare the user's preferred language as a profile property. See [Tutoriel](http://odetocode.com/Articles/440.aspx)

(Note that this is a rephrasing of @Ikaso's answer, so s/he should answer and get credits)

Comment: Ok lets say we have got the culture info in a session variable.
Now where do i have to write the code to the change the language.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the solution you got, you can have your own HTTP module and set the culture there by passing it through the URL for example. But you need to do that in the module before the page lifecycle starts.